# SharePoint 2016 FileNotFound Exception

Tags: c#, sharepoint, automation

Through C#, I'm trying to download a file from SharePoint (SharePoint 2016). Below is the code I'm using:

```
        site = new ClientContext(url);
        //credential setting has no issues. So I am skipping it. I am using NetworkCredentials
        site.Load(web);
        site.ExecuteQuery();
        List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
        site.Load(list);
        site.ExecuteQuery();
        site.Load(list.RootFolder);
        site.ExecuteQuery();
        site.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);
        site.ExecuteQuery();
        Folder folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(sharePointPath);
        site.Load(folder);
        site.ExecuteQuery();
        site.Load(folder.Files);
        site.ExecuteQuery();
```

While the last "site.ExecuteQuery()" is being executed, an exception is thrown:

```
ExceptionMessage: File not found
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream
```

But, there are files in that path and manually we are able to upload and download with the same credentials. URLs, Paths, etc have been double-checked and no issues with that. 
When I print "folder.ItemCount", it is printing the correct no. of files in the folder. Only in ExecuteQuery for loading files, it is throwing exception.

Build settings: .NET framework 4.5 and x64

In other posts, people advised to change to .NET 3.5 but it was for SharePoint 2010. Further, changing it to 3.5 ends up in lot of build errors for me.

Please help in fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet to download a file from SharePoint default Document library and save into a local folder:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string siteUrl = "http://sp2016/sites/dev";
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
            var listItem = list.GetItemById(5);
            clientContext.Load(list);
            clientContext.Load(listItem, i => i.File);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            var fileRef = listItem.File.ServerRelativeUrl;
            var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileRef);
            var fileName = Path.Combine(@"C:\Test", (string)listItem.File.Name);
            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
            {
                fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was working with collection and above solution did not work for me, here is how I did so that it can help someone.

```
List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Events");
ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(cmlqry);
context.Load(listItems);               
context.ExecuteQuery();

if (listItems != null)
{
    foreach (var listItem in listItems)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}, Title: {1}", listItem["ID"].ToString(), listItem["Title"].ToString());

        context.Load(listItem.AttachmentFiles);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (var file in listItem.AttachmentFiles)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File: {0}", file.FileName);
            var fileRef = file.ServerRelativeUrl;
            var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, fileRef);
            var fileName = Path.Combine(@"C:\temp\Events\", String.Format("{0}_{1}", listItem.Id, file.FileName));
            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
            {
                fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);                               
            }

        }

    }
}
```